# Why isn't Guid.ToString("n") the same as a hex string generated from a byte array of the same guid?

Tags: c#, guid, hex

Consider the following unit test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestByteToString()
    {
        var guid = new Guid("61772f3ae5de5f4a8577eb1003c5c054");
        var guidString = guid.ToString("n");
        var byteString = ToHexString(guid.ToByteArray());

        Assert.AreEqual(guidString, byteString);
    }

    private String ToHexString(Byte[] bytes)
    {
        var hex = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length * 2);
        foreach(var b in bytes)
        {
            hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
        }
        return hex.ToString();
    }
```

Here's the result:

`Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<61772f3ae5de5f4a8577eb1003c5c054>. Actual:<3a2f7761dee54a5f8577eb1003c5c054>.`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, they are the same, after the first 4 bytes.  And the first four are the same, just in the reverse order.

Basically, when created from the string, it's assumed to be in "big-endian" format: Highest byte to the left.  However, when stored internally (on an Intel-ish machine), the bytes are ordered "little-endian": highest order byte to the right.

Answer (score 15):

If you compare the results, you can see that the first three groups are reversed:

```
61 77 2f 3a   e5 de   5f 4a   8577eb1003c5c054
3a 2f 77 61   de e5   4a 5f   8577eb1003c5c054
```

That's because in the [GUID structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373931(v=vs.85).aspx), these 3 groups are defined as `DWORD` and two `WORD`s rather than bytes:

```
{0x00000000,0x0000,0x0000,{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}}
```

so in memory, an Intel processor stores them in Little-endian order (the most significant byte the last).

Answer (score 4):

A GUID is structured as follows:

```
int a
short b
short c
byte[8] d
```

So for the part represented by `a` your code gets the bytes reversed. All other parts are transformed correctly.

Comment: why would `b` and `c` not be reversed too?

Comment: @SebastianGodelet - because they are `short` rather than `int`.

Comment: I thought that everything greater than one byte is subject to endianess: `short s = 0xaf21;` could be stored: |af|21| or |21|af|

Comment: @SebastianGodelet - Possibly, but endianness is usually at the `int` level.

Comment: not trying to be nasty, but I think there's a slight misunderstanding here... 16bit integers, c.f. `System.Int16` are also subject to endianess, e.g. : Unicode Transfer encodings: UTF-16LE and UTF-16BE, but only: UTF-8,

Comment: @SebastianGodelet - It's OK. It's been a while since I had to do anything serious with endianness so my memory could well be faulty.