# Incorrect Guid order

Tags: c#, mysql, hex, guid, connector-net

Ok I have a GUID `f5cc4100-f1b4-4af6-9e9e-224b0eb74166` and I am inserting it to MySQL database using the ADO .NET Connector.

I can do it in two ways:

1)  Feed byte array to .NET Connector

```
string query = "insert into test (pk_id) values (@id)";
using (var c = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", new Guid("f5cc4100-f1b4-4af6-9e9e-224b0eb74166").ToByteArray());
    c.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

2) Rely on MySQL standard function to convert hexadecimal to binary string.

```
string query = "insert into test (pk_id) values (UNHEX(@id))";
using (var c = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", "f5cc4100-f1b4-4af6-9e9e-224b0eb74166".Replace("-", "");
    c.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The problem I face is the two above methods inserts the same guid in slightly different character order.

If I am selecting back the inserted guid like this:

```
string query = "select PK_id from test";
using (var c = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    using (var r = c.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (r.Read())
        {
            var k = new Guid((byte[])r[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

I get `f5cc4100-f1b4-4af6-9e9e-224b0eb74166` and `0041ccf5-b4f1-f64a-9e9e-224b0eb74166` back. But if I am reading like this:

```
string query = "select hex(PK_id) from test";
using (var c = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    using (var r = c.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (r.Read())
        {
            var k = new Guid((string)r[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

I get `0041ccf5-b4f1-f64a-9e9e-224b0eb74166` and `f5cc4100-f1b4-4af6-9e9e-224b0eb74166`.

**In short, if I am inserting the GUID as bytearrays, then I need to read them as such and cast as byte arrays to get the right GUID. And if I am inserting the GUID as `UNHEX` of the hexadecimal guid string, then I need to read from db using its equivalent `HEX` function.**

1. Why are writing and reading different with the above two methods?
2. What would be the more appropriate way of handling GUIDs between the two?

Comment: I'm not sure why they're different (I don't have MySql), but you should store the guid as CHAR(16) binary.

Comment: @ChrisGessler I am storing them as binary(16). I do not think a char(16) can hold all of a guid. Did you mean char(36)?

Comment: Read here char(36) or char(16) binary seems to be the way to go.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412341/how-should-i-store-guid-in-mysql-tables

Comment: @ChrisGessler It will be big ask to modify db now. Anyway thanks for letting me know..

Comment: See also [this Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190817/) and [this MSDN question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/c734755e-8102-4aba-9d0f-6c7eba8f14c5).

Comment: ... and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320501/).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Ok that answers why they are different. But as to which to use reliably, I am still confused..

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Can you post it as an answer? Or should I close this question?

Comment: The MySQL Connector/NET has explicit support for Guids, so adding the value as a `Guid` object would seem like a natural choice. If you then enabled `oldguids` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-connection-options.html), your application would be using the connector as intended by the connector developers …

Comment: @hangy `oldguids=true` has got nothing to do with ordering of bytes which is the core problem in my question. [Catch something on what oldguids=true do here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10681245/661933)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Original Poster asked for my comments (which are just links) to be posted as an answer, here it comes:

[SO: Guid Byte Order in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190817/)

[MSDN: System.Guid .ToByteArray swapping first 4 bytes](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/c734755e-8102-4aba-9d0f-6c7eba8f14c5)

[SO: C#: Why isn't Guid.ToString(“n”) the same as a hex string generated from a byte array of the same guid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320501/)

It seems like it's not clearly documented what endianness the different components of the `Guid` possess, when converting to and from `Byte[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Nielsen answers one part of the question. As to which to use, there is nothing that makes a good choice. Either way it fine. If the values in the db will be required to read later outside the .NET world, then MySQL hexing and unhexing will be better. There is a slight (very very slight) performance penalty associated with hexing and unhexing in my tests. If it matters for you, then stick with `ToByteArray()`